# Twitter bootstrap responsive navigation disappears after opening and closing

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap

Having issues with Twitter Bootstrap responsive navigation. The best way to explain this is in steps.

go to: http://library.buffalo.edu/redesign/html/findlibrarymaterials/

Resize the design to below 768px

Open the nav via the button on the top right, then close it

Now resize the design to above 768px

For some reason the navigation disappears after you make the design larger. It reappears after refresh. I'm sure this is something I did with the CSS, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navbar is getting hidden when the 'collapse' class is applied - even if the 'in' class is removed. Try adding (or un-deleting) this:

```
.nav-collapse.collapse {
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: I added this to my main styles...

.nav-collapse.collapse {
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
  }

Seems to be fixed now. Thanks for directing me to the right styles. I appreciate your help. Cheers, Kris

Comment: @eterps for me also had same problem but now with this fiz, it opens.. not closing

Comment: You are a life saver. My navbar was doing something weird after i changed @grid-float-breakpoint and recompiled less where my navbar was expanding but would instantly collapse again. took countless hours to find this (learned a lot in the process though). Thanks for this elegant suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I was very hopeful that eterps's answer would solve my problem since my problem was the exact same one described in the question. However, eterps's answer did not work for me for some reason.

After inspecting my navbar element on Chrome's Inspect Element tool, I found that my navbar had the following property:

```
display: none;
```

For me, this is what fixed it:

```
.nav-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
}
```

No need to put in a media query.

Comment: for bootstrap 3, this property is present in the computed styles at the affected width.

Answer (score 0):

As etaps but use a media query so the rule does not apply when width < $navbarCollapseWidth:

```
@media (min-width: $navbarCollapseWidth + 1) {
  .nav-collapse.collapse {
      height: auto !important;
      overflow: visible !important;
  }
}
```

I am using scss with Compass you may need to use Less syntax.

Comment: It's a few years since this was last answered. I'm searching for a solution to this problem in Bootstrap 4 and nothing I'm finding is working. Is there a special/unique solution for BS4?