# Bootstrap Nav Disappears on Resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 navbar. When I scale the browser window to a low resolution or access the page with my mobile I have no menu. Usually, with Bootstrap I have a collapsed navigation but it is nowhere to be found.

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
              <li class="aktiv" ><a href="advertiser.php">Advertisers</a></li>
              <li><a href="publisher.php">Publishers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutModal">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pressModal">Press</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #333E48;
    border: 0;
    display: block!important; /* From Stack Overflow */
}

.navbar-brand > img,
.navbar-brand {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
}

.navbar-brand > img {
    padding: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.nav-collapse.collapse {
    height: auto !important; /* From Stack Overflow */
    overflow: visible !important; /* From Stack Overflow */
}
```

I added `display: block!important;` to `.navbar` after reading [Nav disappears after resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983734/nav-disappears-after-resize)

I added `height: auto !important; overflow: visible !important;` to `.nav-collapse.collapse` after reading [Twitter bootstrap responsive navigation disappears after opening and closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108949/twitter-bootstrap-responsive-navigation-disappears-after-opening-and-closing)

Issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear in your question but your missing the toggle button to open and close the menu when your viewport is reduced, otherwise the mobile menu will always be open.

```css
nav.navbar-default  {
  background: #333E48;
  border: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand > img,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand > img {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  line-height: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .nav-collapse.collapse {
  height: auto !important;
  /* From Stack Overflow */
  overflow: visible !important;
  /* From Stack Overflow */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/fff/fff" />
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="aktiv"><a href="advertiser.php">Advertisers</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="publisher.php">Publishers</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutModal">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pressModal">Press</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have to remove the `collapse` class on  `div#navbar`

Here is a [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/tiEYuUjPuo)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
              <li class="aktiv" ><a href="advertiser.php">Advertisers</a></li>
              <li><a href="publisher.php">Publishers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutModal">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pressModal">Press</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

*And rewrite the css for the xs view*